# Java Decyption logic throwing BadpaddingException But its working in .NET

Tags: java, .net

.NET code
 public  String Decrypt(string encryptedString)
    {

```
         byte[]   toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString)
         MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
         byte[]  keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key));              
            hashmd5.Clear(); 
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; 
        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(
                             toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);

    }
```

Java code

public void decryptin(String encryptedText) throws Exception{

```
    byte[] message = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] digestOfUsername = md.digest(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfUsername, 24);
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding",new SunJCE());
        decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);// BadpaddingException 
        String decryptedString = new String(plainText);
```

}

.NET code working fine but java is code is not give the proper output
its giving BadpaddingException : at dofinal() please correct me where i am doing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is that you are converting the encrypted bytes to a hex string (using the asHex method) but are not converting the hex string back to a byte array correctly for decryption. You can't use getBytes.

You can use the following method to convert a hex string to a byte array:

```
public static byte[] fromHexString(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

and then change your decrypt method to use:

```
original = decipher.doFinal(fromHexString(message));
```

Comment: Thanks friend. i changed the code as u said for encrypted string it is giving this exception:
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the ans :

public void decrypt(String encryptedText)throws Exception {

```
    byte[] message = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedText);
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(kEY.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[24];
    System.arraycopy(digestOfPassword, 0, keyBytes, 0, 16);
    System.arraycopy(digestOfPassword, 0, keyBytes, 16, 8);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
    Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);
    String decryptedString = new String(plainText, UTF);

}
```